# Generate multiples in Robot script using RandInt

Tags: robotframework, faker

I would like to generate fake numbers where one is multiple of the other. Currently I have a python file being passed into my Robot script.

```
*** Settings ***
Library                ../scripts/param.py
*** Test Cases ***
ABC
    ${ans}             parameter  2  8  30
    ${c}=              Set Variable   ${ans[1]}
    ${T}=              Set Variable   ${ans[0]}
```

and my param.py is:

```
import random


def parameter(min_no: int, max_no: int, multiplier: int):
    integer = random.randint(min_no, max_no)
    return integer, integer * multiplier
```

But I would like to include this logic within my Robot script. Please let me know the best way of doing this.

Comment: Your code doesn't use `Faker`, why is that mentioned in the title?

Answer (score 1):

You can call python code using [inline python evaluation](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#id117)

```
*** Test Cases ***
AC
    ${c}=  set variable  ${{random.randint(2, 8)}}
    ${t}=  set variable  ${{$c * 30}}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply @bryan . I have corrected the title. And I tried this as well as the below code:     ```${c}=  Evaluate  random.randint(2, 8)   ${t}= Evaluate  ${c} * 30. ``` But both gives me the same error: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'lower'

Comment: @Reshma: it's telling the truth: an int doesn't have a method named `lower`. What do you think is supposed to happen when converting a number to lowercase? Though, I don't think it's possible for the code in your comment to give that error since you don't call `lower` anywhere.

Comment: But I do get this error, and my code consists on only these 2 lines and then I'm just logging these 2 values to console. I'm not using lower anywhere.

Comment: @Reshma: when I paste those two statements with Evaluate into a brand new file and run it as a test, I don't get any errors. The code I posted also doesn't give any errors.

Comment: ```Log To Console      ${c} ${t}``` it was just indentation issue. Thank you soo much!!!